# google chrome local storage not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

In my Bookmark application when i am trying to insert bookmarks in the local storage after clicking on the submit button i shouls see the contents in the local storage but it does not show a file at all.
 my javascript file:

```
//listener for form submit
document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('submit',savebookmark);
//function savebookmark
function savebookmark(e)
{   //var for holding sitename and siteurl
    var siteName=document.getElementById('sitename').value;
    var siteUrl=document.getElementById('siteurl').value;
    var bookmark={
        name:siteName,
        url:siteUrl
    }
    /*  
    localStorage.setItem('test', 'hello world!!');
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('test'));
    localStorage.removeItem('test');
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('test'));
*/
//test if bookmark is null
     if(window.localStorage.getItem('bookmarks') === null){
    // Init array
    var bookmarks = [];
    // Add to array
    bookmarks.push(bookmark);
    // Set to localStorage
    window.localStorage.setItem('bookmarks', JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
  }

        //prevent from from submitting
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>BOOKMARKER</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="header clearfix">
        <nav>

        </nav>
        <h1 class="text-muted">BOOKMARKER</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2 class="display-3">Bookmark your Site</h2>
        <form id="myform">
        <div class="form group">
         <label>SITE NAME</label>
         <input type="text" class="formcontrol" id="sitename" placeholder="Website name">
        </div>
        <div class="form group">
         <label>SITE URL</label>
         <input type="text" class="formcontrol" id="siteurl" placeholder="Website URL">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="row marketing">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div id="bookmarksresult">

          </div>
        </div>


      </div>

      <footer class="footer">
        <p>&copy; Bookmarker 2017</p>
      </footer>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
    crossorigin="anonymous"> 
    </script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't very descriptive.  Are you getting any errors in your console?

Answer (score 0):

I see when trying to run as a snippet I get:

VM128 js:99 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.
    at HTMLFormElement.savebookmark (http://stacksnippets.net/js:99:13)

However, I was able to get it work successfully with this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/tafjn3dd/

http://prntscr.com/f6q7d5 (screenshot)

```js
//listener for form submit
document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('submit', savebookmark);
//function savebookmark
function savebookmark(e)

{
  //prevent from from submitting
  e.preventDefault();

  //var for holding sitename and siteurl
  var siteName = document.getElementById('sitename').value;
  var siteUrl = document.getElementById('siteurl').value;
  var bookmark = {
    name: siteName,
    url: siteUrl
  }
  /*  
    localStorage.setItem('test', 'hello world!!');
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('test'));
    localStorage.removeItem('test');
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('test'));
*/
  //test if bookmark is null
  if (window.localStorage.getItem('bookmarks') === null) {
    // Init array
    var bookmarks = [];
    // Add to array
    bookmarks.push(bookmark);
    // Set to localStorage
    window.localStorage.setItem('bookmarks', JSON.stringify(bookmarks));
  }


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <title>BOOKMARKER</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="header clearfix">
      <nav>

      </nav>
      <h1 class="text-muted">BOOKMARKER</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h2 class="display-3">Bookmark your Site</h2>
      <form id="myform">
        <div class="form group">
          <label>SITE NAME</label>
          <input type="text" class="formcontrol" id="sitename" placeholder="Website name">
        </div>
        <div class="form group">
          <label>SITE URL</label>
          <input type="text" class="formcontrol" id="siteurl" placeholder="Website URL">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="row marketing">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div id="bookmarksresult">

        </div>
      </div>


    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
      <p>&copy; Bookmarker 2017</p>
    </footer>

  </div>
  <!-- /container -->

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
  <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```